# Fuzzy java parser in Antlr 4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

In 2012, Terence Parr wrote:

"added fuzzy java "parser" to v4 examples page

Hi,

Check out the bottom of this page for a fuzzy Java parser that uses just lexical rules to grab items of interest:

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Examples

Ter"

But the page is "404" and I cannot find this grammar. Anybody has a copy? Or a pointer to another fuzzy or error-recovery Java grammar?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120504181858/http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Examples

Comment: ask this guy http://stackoverflow.com/users/275496/the-antlr-guy

Answer (score 0):

Many years after the question, but the grammar is in the ANTLR4 documentation [Wildcard Operator and Nongreedy Subrules](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/4.9.1/doc/wildcard.md#nongreedy-parser-subrules)

```
grammar FuzzyJava;
 
/** Match anything in between constant rule matches */
file : .*? (constant .*?)+ ;
 
/** Faster alternate version (Gets an ANTLR tool warning about
 * a subrule like .* in parser that you can ignore.)
 */
altfile : (constant | .)* ; // match a constant or any token, 0-or-more times

/** Match things like "public static final SIZE" followed by anything */
constant
    :   'public' 'static' 'final' 'int' Identifier
        {System.out.println("constant: "+$Identifier.text);}
    ;
 
Identifier : [a-zA-Z_$] [a-zA-Z_$0-9]* ; // simplified
```